# Programação Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Erro no Segundo "public class", o que posso fazer???

Se alguem souber digam por favor.

Obrigado.

```
package com.example.hsantos_98.artofthefire;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

View myView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_layout, container, false);
    return myView;
}

public class ThirdFragment extends AppCompatActivity { 
    Animation fade_in, fade_out;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)  this.findViewById(R.id.bckgrndViewFlipper1);
        fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fade_in);
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fade_out);

        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
        viewFlipper.startFlipping();
    }

}
```

Comment: As classes não podem ter nomes iguais estando no mesmo pacote ou mesmo arquivo. Tente renomear.

Comment: extends Fragment  e extends AppCompatActivity Preciso de as por na mesma class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java não permite que duas classes no mesmo pacote tenham o mesmo nome. O que você deve fazer é renomear uma delas. Outra restrição é que mais de uma classe pública só pode ser declarada no mesmo arquivo se for inner class, ou seja, se for uma classe "interna" a classe pública principal. Como no teu caso é uma classe e uma inner class, vai dar certo.

OBS: Também é importante frisar que não faz sentido dar o mesmo nome a algo que tem comportamentos diferentes (Fragment e AppCompatActivity). Dessa forma, sugiro que você reveja o propósito de cada classe para nomeá-las adequadamente.